# Postgis calculate the distance between points more than two

Tags: postgis

I have a table that has a position in it. Is there any solid way to calculate the distance between A --> B --> C --> D etc using Postgis.

```
Distance = AB + AC + CD etc.
```

Each point has {lat, lng}.

I appreciate any help you can provide.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `lead` or `lag` to work with next/previous row of a [window](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-window.html). You can then compute the distance and `sum` it if you want, in an outer query.

```sql
SELECT sum(dist) 
FROM (
  SELECT id, ST_DistanceSphere(geom, lead(geom) OVER(ORDER BY id)) as dist 
  FROM myTable) sub;
```